When I build the project in VS C# WF where does the project build stop and the names of the executable file, configuration, and database are changed?؟
I work on Visual Studio C# Windows Forms and I have a project that contains two applications that were working properly without any problems. After the release of the fifth version a few days ago, when I build the project, it shows incorrect error messages, which is the absence of some libraries for reports. When I try to rebuild, it gives me a message that the project's executable file does not exist. When I open the following program folder bin/64/Debug. I find the executable file, the configuration file, and the database files. The following phrase has been added to their names, so the name of the executable file becomes in the following format App1-DESKTOP-3A25GOE.exe
instead of App1.exe
As for the rest of the files, the phrase "-DESKTOP-3A25GOE" is added to them and Visual Basic cannot recognize them. When this phrase is deleted, the project works after overcoming the false errors and opens the third version.
It is clear that it is a virus. How do I get rid of it, knowing that I have deleted the program more than once and restored healthy copies, but the problem returns every time. I also downloaded known virus programs one after the other and did not discover any virus.
I have become helpless and my work has stopped. If anyone has a solution, please let me know and I will be grateful to you.

Don't know why that happens, but DESKTOP-3A25GOE looks like your Windows computer name. You can verify that by start->run...->cmd.exe, then running set comp - will probably show COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-3A25GO

What does VS' Output window show after rebuild? It usually shows App1 -> c:\...\App1.exe

It's almost certainly not a virus! Check your .csproj file for AssemblyName.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/259382/file-name-suffixed-by-computer-name

There are three false errors appearing, the first error is related to the Crystal Report library and the other two are related to the Office library and they are all present. The problem is that these errors are constant and every time it gives me other errors and if I repeat the build process it changes the file names
